# I need to get all numbers without a decimal point multipliable by 1.05

Tags: c

The console doesn't output anything it just outputs the printf function and then stops

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float multiplier = 1.05;
    int i;

    printf("Numbers multipliable by 1.05 without a decimal point:\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= 5000000000000000; i+ 1) {
        float result = i * multiplier;
        if ((int)result == result) { // Check if the result is an integer
            printf("%.0f\n", result); // Print the result without decimal point
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `i++` or `i+=1` instead of `i+ 1`

Comment: On most systems, `5000000000000000` is too large for `int` (which is usually 32 bit). Since you only need positive integers, you should use `uint64_t`.

Comment: Also, mathematically its easy to see that you're interested in numbers that are a multiple of 21 (the lowest common multiple of 1 and 1.05)

Comment: Your's going to be out of luck using floating point, since `1.05` isn't exactly representable. I suggest you do `i * 105 / 100` instead. Or `i * 105` and see if there is a remainder if divided by `100`.

Comment: According to your first `printf()`, you should be printing out the value of `i`, not `result`. It's 'Numbers _multipliable_ by 1.05', not 'Numbers _after_ _multiplying_ by 1.05'...

Comment: @gulpr OP appears to be attempting to print all the positive integers that are a multiple of 1.05 (how im interpreting "multipliable" since all numbers can be multiplied by 1.05). This occurs every 20th step of the loop, i.e. when result = i*20*1.05 = i*21. In other words, the print statement should print multiples of 21.

Comment: Maybe we need OP to clarify what they actually mean. It can be interpreted as either "without a decimal point if multiplied by 1.05" or "without a decimal point and multiple of 1.05".

Comment: @jodag You're right in what you're saying. The question isn't clear. for N*21/20 to be an integer N needs to be a multiple of 20 and the result will be a multiple of 21.  Obviously 1.05=21/20 in it simplest terms.

Comment: @ouuan The question isn't well worded I *think* it means "I need to get all numbers without a decimal point (i.e. integers) that are multiples of 1.05". That's multiples of 21 but 1.05 needs multiplying by 20 to get them.

Answer (score 4):

You are searching for numbers that are multiples of 20. You don't need to test each number. You can just enumerate with a step of 20 and print all of them:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Numbers multipliable by 1.05 without a decimal point:\n");

    for (int i = 20; i <= 100000; i += 20) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This task does not require brute force and floats. You need to analyze the problem before starting programming

1.05 multiplied by `x` will give an integer (in math understanding) only if `x` is divisible by `1/0.05` - ie `20`.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50000; i += 1) 
    {
        if(!(i % 20)) printf("%d\n", i);
    }
```

As mentioned in comments

- `i += 1` not `i + 1`
- `5000000000000000` is too large number for the integer.

Comment: Please use ```i++``` even though it does the same as ```i+=1```.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: Why?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh what?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Using more compact language features when possible.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: Conciseness is often nice, but it is not an overriding consideration.

Answer (score 0):

1.05 = 105/100 which simplifies to 21/20 (simplest terms because 21 and 20 have no common factors).
N*21/20 for integer N is itself an integer if (and only if) 20 divides N.
(If that's not obvious I'll add a footnote).

Your question is ambiguous but your program appears to be trying to output numbers that are *integer* multiples of 1.05 that are integers. That is you're outputting N*21/20 rather than N.

Without getting bogged down in floating-point arithmetic here's a program that lays the process bear.

You've started N (i in your notation) at 1 but I'll start at 0 (a multiple of 20 after all). You can deal with negative numbers yourself it that's required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

const int INT_FROM=0;
const int INT_TO=10000; //Use INT_MAX if you want all ints in range.


int main(void) {
    const int num=21; //Numerator
    const int den=20; //Denominator

    double dbl=((double)num)/den;

    int j=0;
    for(;;){
        int N=j*den;
        int R=j*num;
        printf("%d. %d*%f = %d\n",(j+1),N,dbl,R);
        if((INT_TO-num)<=R || (INT_TO-den)<=N){
            break;
        } 
        ++j;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Typical Output (truncated output):

```
1. 0*1.050000 = 0
2. 20*1.050000 = 21
3. 40*1.050000 = 42
4. 60*1.050000 = 63
5. 80*1.050000 = 84
6. 100*1.050000 = 105
7. 120*1.050000 = 126
8. 140*1.050000 = 147
9. 160*1.050000 = 168
10. 180*1.050000 = 189
11. 200*1.050000 = 210
```

This bit is worth comment:

```
if((INT_TO-num)<=R || (INT_TO-den)<=N){
    break;
}
```

If you use a value for `INT_TO` at or close to `INT_MAX` we have to avoid overflow. So that bit works out whether the next iteration will cause overflow rather than naive logic that tries to detect overflow when it's happened.
Also it should be clear that because 1.05 > 1 the first part of the OR will be true before the second. I've put that in in case you want to play with numbers less than 1.00.

You specified 1.05 so I've not provided code inferring a rational number representing some provided fault. I'd say that's a different topic.